# reaching 5000 items in a list

Tags: list, office-365, threshold

I have made a test and reached 5020 items in a list. I get this message in the list settings 'The number of items in this list exceeds the list view threshold, which is 5000 items. Tasks that cause excessive server load (such as those involving all list items) are currently prohibited.'

I can still add items to the list, however the above message sounds threatening enough. Do you know if Microsoft has got alerts on their end and might decide to restrict throttling or other parameters on the tenancy?

Answer (score 2):

For Office 365, this is hard limit and can not be modified. You will need to redesign application to work around this limit.

When using Office 365 interface there are following ways to do this:

1. Organize items in folders such that no folder in list/library has more than total of 5000 items/documents and folders. One can come up with appropriate folder structure based on business sense of the application.
2. Use Indexes on field which are used to fetch data.
3. Instead of using "All Items" view, create your own view which filter data on indexed fields such that no more that 5000 records are part of view.

Reference [Manage large lists and libraries in SharePoint](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Manage-large-lists-and-libraries-in-SharePoint-b8588dae-9387-48c2-9248-c24122f07c59)

Comment: this does not necessarily answer my question

Comment: ok. which part of the question is still unanswered?

Comment: Do you know if Microsoft has got alerts on their end and might decide to restrict throttling or other parameters on the tenancy?

Comment: Microsoft has developed "Office 365" as a product just like "MS Word" and has a number of constraints for it's usage and functioning. These are build into platform. Microsoft updates/patches platform every 2 month. Links below lists such constraints in detail.

https://technet.microsoft.com/library/Cc262787.aspx

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SharePoint-Online-software-boundaries-and-limits-8f34ff47-b749-408b-abc0-b605e1f6d498

Wherever content in both contradict, the second document overrides the first one. Microsoft can introduce new restriction/feature with every update.